# How to modify temp table inside cursor?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

I have temp table data in sql. I need modify data in that table.

Please find snapshot attached
[image]

I need to have a col having month data like for 01-03 jan-mar
this is code I have written. It's not working:

```
DECLARE @month VARCHAR(50) -- month
DECLARE @year VARCHAR(256) -- year
DECLARE @monthf VARCHAR(256) -- year
DECLARE @months VARCHAR(256) -- year

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT months,[year] FROM #temp where len(months)>4

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @month,@year  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

    IF SUBSTRING(@month,0,3) = '01'
    set @monthf='Jan'      
    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@month,0,3) = '02'
    set @monthf='Feb'
    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@month,0,3) = '03'
    set @monthf='Mar'
    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@month,0,3) = '04'
    set @monthf='Apr'
    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@month,0,3) = '05'
    set @monthf='May'
    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@month,0,3) = '06'
    set @monthf='Jun'
    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@month,0,3) = '07'
    set @monthf='Jul'
    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@month,0,3) = '08'
    set @monthf='Aug'
    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@month,0,3) = '09'
    set @monthf='Sep'
    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@month,0,3) = '10'
    set @monthf='Oct'
    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@month,0,3) = '11'
    set @monthf='Nov'
    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@month,0,3) = '12'
    set @monthf='Dec'

    IF SUBSTRING(@month,4,2) = '01'
    set @months='Jan'      
    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@month,4,2) = '02'
    set @months='Feb'
    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@month,4,2) = '03'
    set @months='Mar'
    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@month,4,2) = '04'
    set @months='Apr'
    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@month,4,2) = '05'
    set @months='May'
    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@month,4,2) = '06'
    set @months='Jun'
    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@month,4,2) = '07'
    set @months='Jul'
    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@month,4,2) = '08'
    set @months='Aug'
    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@month,4,2) = '09'
    set @months='Sep'
    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@month,4,2) = '10'
    set @months='Oct'
    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@month,4,2) = '11'
    set @months='Nov'
    ELSE IF SUBSTRING(@month,4,2) = '12'
    set @months='Dec'


      update #temp set [Month]= where months=

      Delete from #temp where months=SUBSTRING(@month,0,3) and [Year]=@year
      Delete from #temp where months=SUBSTRING(@month,4,2) and [Year]=@year  


      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @month,@year   
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

I need another column with month names like: for 01-03 it should give jan-mar
Can you please help me out? I need a separate column for month string data.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (And I can't read that tiny image text...)

Comment: Here's a good place to start: [Forum Etiquette: how to post data for a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/). On a different note, I doubt a `CURSOR` is needed for this, but i'll wait to see the data before commiting to any kind of answer.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a cursor at all.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Data') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Data

CREATE TABLE #Data (
    Month VARCHAR(100),
    ResultMonthText VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #Data (
    Month)
VALUES
    ('01-03'),
    ('07'),
    ('03'),
    ('03-05'),
    ('05-09'),
    ('02')

;WITH ParsedMonths AS
(
    SELECT
        D.Month,
        D.ResultMonthText,
        First = CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(D.Month, 1, 2)),
        Second = CONVERT(INT, NULLIF(SUBSTRING(D.Month, 4, 2), ''))
    FROM
        #Data AS D
),
MonthNames AS
(
    SELECT
        D.Month,
        D.ResultMonthText,
        FirstAsName = SUBSTRING(
            DATENAME(
                MONTH, 
                DATEADD(MONTH, D.First, 0) - 1 ),
            1,
            3),
        SecondAsName = SUBSTRING(
            DATENAME(
                MONTH, 
                DATEADD(MONTH, D.Second, 0) - 1 ),
            1,
            3)
    FROM
        ParsedMonths AS D
)
UPDATE D SET
    ResultMonthText = D.FirstAsName + ISNULL('-' + D.SecondAsName, '')
FROM
    MonthNames AS D



SELECT
    *
FROM
    #Data AS D

/*
Result:

    Month   ResultMonthText
    ------- ------------
    01-03   Jan-Mar
    07      Jul
    03      Mar
    03-05   Mar-May
    05-09   May-Sep
    02      Feb

*/
```

**EDIT:** Do this if you still want to keep your cursor (although I strongly suggest you stop using them whenever you can):

```
OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @month,@year  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN 

    DECLARE @FirstMonthNumber INT = CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@month, 1, 2))
    DECLARE @SecondMonthNumber INT = CONVERT(INT, NULLIF(SUBSTRING(@month, 4, 2), ''))

    DECLARE @FirstMonthText VARCHAR(10) = SUBSTRING(
        DATENAME(
            MONTH, 
            DATEADD(MONTH, @FirstMonthNumber, 0) - 1 ),
        1,
        3)

    DECLARE @SecondMonthText VARCHAR(10) = SUBSTRING(
        DATENAME(
            MONTH, 
            DATEADD(MONTH, @SecondMonthNumber, 0) - 1 ),
        1,
        3)

    update #temp set 
        YourNewMonthColumn = @FirstMonthText + ISNULL('-' + @SecondMonthText, '')
    WHERE
        months = @month

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @month,@year

END
```

I don't know why you update the column and then delete the row also.

Comment: i need cursor as i have to delete some rows in loop so can this code be placed inside cursor

Comment: @deepti no you don't. SQL works with *sets* not loops. You *don't* need a loop to work with multiple rows even if you need to combine multiple tables. You need to write the appropriate SQL statement. It's actually a *lot* easier to do so

Comment: @deepti in fact, you probably don't need to write anything - you can create a Calendar or Date table with eg 20 years worth of dates and names, join with it and filter on its year/month columns. Even a very large Calendar table takes minimal storage

Comment: I'll always throw in a vote for a Calendar Table. They are probably the most useful thing in a database. And just an FYI, if you ever think you _need_ to use a cursor, you should probably take a step back and figure out why. Then figure out how else you can do it. There are very few cases where a cursor is the best option. Or even a Top 5 option.

Comment: how can above solution be incorporated with exisitng temp table

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
update #temp set [Month] = @monthf where months = @months
```

Comment: i need monthf-months both, need to concatentenate 2 mmonths jan-mar

Comment: Well right now it is not even updating a single month.